# C# - Up to date torrent library?

Tags: library, c#, bittorrent

I'm looking forward to build an application that would rely on torrent functionality. I've done some research, but I can't seem to find an actively developed and maintained library.

My findings so far:

- [MonoTorrent](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoTorrent/) Last update in 2013 March
- [OctoTorrent](http://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoTorrent/0.1.8-rc) Last update in 2013 April
- [EasyTorrent](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyTorrent/) Last update in 2013 March
- [System.Net.Torrent](https://github.com/bizzehdee/System.Net.Torrent) <s>Last update in 2014 October, lacks simple client implementation and is incomplete as is</s> **EDIT 2018.01.04:** System.Net.Torrent has been kept up-to-date recently, and works quite well, albeit for my goals it still misses the client implementation

Are there any other torrent libraries that are relatively simple to implement?

The features I'm looking for:

- Torrent download/upload, in a controllable fashion
- Reporting of single torrent status, download speed, peers, tracker information, etc.
- Torrent creation (not necessary but would be nice)

Comment: Would a C++ library work? I'm thinking http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/libaria2.html

Comment: My question intentionally targets .Net&C# - I would prefer a completely managed implementation. Otherwise your suggestion (and Ragnar below) would work perfectly :)

Comment: Any luck yet? I'm looking for the same thing, but I want both tracker and client functionality.

Comment: In what way is System.Net.Torrent incomplete? It fully implements the bittorrent protocol  and quite a lot of the additional BEP's. It doesnt have a client implementation because it is as it is described, a protocol library, you build the client on top of the library yourself.

Comment: @bizzehdee at the time of posting this question, System.Net.Torrent wasn't updated for over half a year (at least no public commits were pushed to GitHub), and had some of the features that are currently checked as complete, missing. I can see that now they are finished and you've been working on it lately, and such, I'll update my question :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had luck with [Ragnar](https://github.com/libragnar/ragnar) which is a CLI wrapper for the C++ library [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/).  I would prefer to use a fully managed solution but this is the only library which I could get working.